# How can I divide a list in 2 parts?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, view

I have a list with 12 items, but I want to divide this list with just 6 items in 2 div's side by side, I don't know how, can someone help me?

```html
<td class="col-md-2 text-uppercase">
  <div class="collapse" id="divRows-@item.BandeiraAdministradoraId">
  @foreach (var taxa in item.TaxaBandeiraAdministradoras)
  {
      <div style="padding-left: 100px;">                 
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => taxa.NumeroTaxas, new {@class = "text-uppercase"})
        @Html.Raw("X =")                                 
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => taxa.ValorTaxa, new {@class = "text-uppercase"})
        @Html.Raw("%")
        <br/>
      </div>
  }
  </div>
</td>
```

[This is the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2kcg.png)

Comment: Why a div in a table cell? Instead look at columns: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts

Comment: It doesn't work ='(

Comment: That is no a useful statement. What does not work? What exactly did you try?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to put the class of css of the example that you send me in the style tag of my div, but doesn't work

Comment: Please create a [mcve] using the snippet editor `<>` using an example of rendered html instead of template code

Comment: It continue the same way that was before

Comment: Sorry is just because I'm not very well in english, so is dificult for me undestanding how to use StackOverFlow, is my first time here

Comment: I'll try to explaine better for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```css
.col {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
  <div class="collapse col" id="divRows-1">
      <div style="padding-left: 100px;">
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      </div>
      <div style="padding-left: 100px;">
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      </div>
      <div style="padding-left: 100px;">
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      </div>
      <div style="padding-left: 100px;">
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      </div>
      <div style="padding-left: 100px;">
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      </div>
      <div style="padding-left: 100px;">
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      taxas
      </div>
  </div>
```